# Файлы .doc

Tags: doc, php, файлы

Приветствую! С новым годом!

Появилась нужда с помощью php открыть .doc файлы. Как это можно осуществить? Желательно чтоб вся структура файла сохранилась(таблицы, перечисления, может ещё шрифт).

Заранее спасибо.

ps. Возможны предложения по тому ещё как открыть .docx

Comment: Погуглите, там есть информация по этому поводу.

Comment: Видел пару постов на Хабре :) Но там как то жутко написано :) поэтому может есть способ легче или может даже встроен в php? ;D

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам подходит способ через COM объект, то [вот](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/extracting-text-from-word-documents-via-php-and-com-81/) есть пример.

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Could not initialise MS Word object."); // сообщение о ошибке если что-то не так

$word->Documents->Open(realpath("Sample.doc"));

// Получить содержимое  
$content = (string) $word->ActiveDocument->Content;

echo $content;

$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);

$word->Quit();  
$word = null;  
unset($word);
```

Comment: Не дружу с английский к сожалению. =(

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.